# How to access a key using the dot operator on an object in which the key begins with :_ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a [beginners' Nodejs API project](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/back-end-development-and-apis-projects/exercise-tracker)
I am required to post to API endpoint /api/users/:_id/exercises and when I get req.body, it has the following form wehen I do a console.log():

```js
    {
      ':_id': '61d0c0b2fa1547d5c637e03c',
      description: 'Pusups',
      duration: '25',
      date: '2021-12-29'
    }
```

Now, I am trying to get the values of these objects by using their keys and a dot operator but I can't find a way to get the key of the object that has the value 61d0c0b2fa1547d5c637e03c. I can access req.body.description and req.body.duration and req.body,date but I can not access req.body.:_id.

I tried the follwoing to practice and find a way to access they first property in this object but I couldn't.

```js
const object1 = {
  ':_id': '61d0c0b2fa1547d5c637e03c',
  description: 'Pusups',
  duration: '25',
  date: '2021-12-29'
}
    let someArray = Object.keys(object1);
    console.log(object1.description);
    console.log(object1.duration);
    console.log(object1.date);
    const someVariable = someArray[0].substring(0, 4);
    console.log(someVariable);
    console.log(object1.someVariable);
    console.log(object1._id);
```

> Pusups
> 25
> 2021-12-29
> :_id
> undefined
> undefined

When I try to post to API endpoint /api/users/:_id/exercises, the post attempt fails. Here is my post function:

```js
app.post('/api/users/:_id/exercises', async function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body);
    if (req.body) {
      //new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString()
      const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.':_id');
      try {
        const newExercise = await addNewExercise(
          {
            _id: id,
            description: req.body.description,
            duration: req.body.duration,
            date: req.body.date ? req.body.date : null
          }
        );
        console.log(newExercise);
        res.json(
          {
            username: newExercise.username,
            description: newExercise.description,
            duration: newExercise.duration,
            date: newExercise.date,
            _id: newExercise._id
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the intention of this line:

```
app.post('/api/users/:_id/exercises', async function(req, res, next) {
```

This is an example of [Express route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). From the Express documentation:

> Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. The captured values are populated in the req.params object, with the name of the route parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.

Instead of making requests to the literal endpoint `/api/users/:_id/exercises`, you would make a request to something like `/api/users/<someUserId>/exercises`, where `someUserId` is a valid ObjectId. You would then retrieve this value in your code with `req.params._id`.

Comment: Thank you very much. After using req.params I get _id instead of :_id. You found it out that my problem was different than I put in the question. My tests still fail and the reason may be that the exercis posted is saved in the mongoDB like this:
_id: ObjectId("61d18459e87c2ccb548ddf89")
username: "fcc_test_16411208573"
description: "Pushups"
duration: 25
date: "2021-12-29". But the test case expect this to be: _id: 61d18459e87c2ccb548ddf89 . I am using this to make the id.                            
    const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);

Comment: @Emil You can use `toString()` on an [ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) to get the hexadecimal string.

Comment: For anyone who stumble upon this and have the same problem in future. Apart from Mongomery's solution, may be you would stumble upon another related problem which is hitting the API end point for getting logs of exercies. Although you migh store the duration of the exercise as Number but mongoDb returns it as string and due to that the test cases fail. Cast duration to number again before sending it to client in res.json().

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by doing

```js
const id = req.body[':_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can access it:

```js
console.log(object1[":_id"]);
```

I don't think it is possible to do it using dot operator but I don't think is a problem as long as you can access the field.

Answer (score 0):

How using the Object.values() method?

```
let firstValue= Object.values(object1)[0];
let secondValue= Object.values(object1)[1];

console.log(firstValue); //logs 61d0c0b2fa1547d5c637e03c
console.log(secondValue);//logs pusups
```